# Ngnix as tomcat front-end

Tags: tomcat

I want to configure Nx as front-end for my tomcat6 server which is running  on 8080 port to serve my grail app. I did the basic setting as listed below. But facing some unknown issue where landing page is working fine through using forced https but whenever I try to log into my application, it bypass Nx and go directly to 8080 port which is not desired.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
    listen   443 default ssl;
    root /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    if ($scheme = http) {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_connect_timeout      240;
            proxy_send_timeout         240;
            proxy_read_timeout         240;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leveraging the proxy_pass header, but it looks like you are missing the X-Real-IP header:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Comment: I tried adding X-Real-IP but the results were same. BTW, is there anything I need to do at tomcat end?

Comment: No, these changes should work without Tomcat configuration changes or restart. I will dig some more and see what else I can find.

Comment: JFYI this is EC2 instance so does NATTING can be a problem like we have one elastic IP which is assigned to this instance while instance is running using a local ip i-e 10.x.x.x?

Comment: OK, finally I was able to solve the mystery. The issue was with GrailServerURL declaration where 8080 port was hard-coded after removing that the above config working like a charm

Comment: Great! It may be helpful to tag your question with other helpful tags, such as "nginx" and "aws", in case others have the same issue.